# java thread dump analysis

Tags: java, threads, jvm

For context: we have been having some issues with garbage collection where we see it taking 15-40 seconds, during this time the application is in a 'paused' state.

Here's what we see in our gabage collection logs
'Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=14.54 sec'

The fact that the user/sys times are ver small and the real is large, (I think) this means that the act of garbage collection took a short amount of time but for some reason the application was waiting for threads to reach a safe point.  we've managed to get a thread dump during one of these pauses and I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm looking at here:

```
"AsyncAppender-Worker-JVM_ASYNC" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd8daaa5800 nid=0x4ed5 waiting on condition [0x00007fd90abf2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c1876d30> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObje

"RMI RenewClean-[10.12.113.3:40608]" #21 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd83401c800 nid=0x4ed2 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd90aff4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
        - locked <0x00000000c18b23a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient$EndpointEntry$RenewCleanThread.run(DGCClient.java:536)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


"RMI Reaper" #17 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd8dbfb0000 nid=0x4ece in Object.wait() [0x00007fd90b7f6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000c0002d00> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
        - locked <0x00000000c0002d00> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
        at sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable$Reaper.run(ObjectTable.java:351)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: we are running on redhat 7.4

Comment: Read this carefully:  https://www.evanjones.ca/jvm-mmap-pause.html  It may be applicable.

Comment: thanks @AndrewHenle, smells pretty similar, I'll take a look